# PayPal Express Checkout GetExpressCheckoutDetails Providing Incorrect Address

Tags: paypal

I am setting up PayPal Express Checkout on my site and am currently in sandbox mode.

I go to checkout as a "user" and add and select a new address on the PayPal Approval page. Then when I run GetExpressCheckoutDetails it still provides me the original address.

When I provide the address in SetExpressCheckout then that address or the address already in the user profile are available, if selected. However, if I add and select a new address and run GetExpressCheckoutDetails I am provided with the address sent over in SetExpressCheckout.

Hopefully, that is not too confusing and someone out there is able to help me.

Thank you!